# Neo4j/Cypher Create nodes from multiple nested json

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am trying to create graph from the sample data below. I am new to cypher and learned new things from tutorial and stack help. I am stuck at the problem below. I am trying to create nodes from nested arrays for multiple properties.

Following the link: [UNWIND multiple unrelated arrays loaded from JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618338/unwind-multiple-unrelated-arrays-loaded-from-json-file)

Sample Data:

```
[   {   'organization': ['MIT','Univ. of CT'],
        'student_names': ['Adam Smith'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC123'},
    {   'organization': ['Harvard'],
        'student_names': ['Adam Smith', 'Cate Scott'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC124'},
    {   'organization': ['Harvard'],
        'student_names': ['Mandy T.', 'Bob Smith'],
        'unique_id': 'ABC125'}]
```

Here is what I tried:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///test2.json') YIELD value AS class
MERGE (c:Class {name: class.name})
SET
c.organization = class.organization,
c.student_names = class.student_names

WITH c, class
UNWIND class.organization AS org
MERGE (o:Organization {name: org})
MERGE (o)-[:ACCEPTED]->(c)

WITH c, class
UNWIND class.student_names AS student
MERGE (s:StudentName {name: student})
MERGE (s)-[:ATTENDS]->(o)
```

I keep getting error `Neo.ClientError.Statement.SemanticError: Cannot merge node using null property value for name`. I don't see any null values in the data. What is causing this? How can I fix this? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MERGE doesn't work if the property on which you merging has a null value.

Here, with `MERGE (c:Class {name: class.name})` You are trying merge Class node on the property **name** but there is no such a property in the json.

I guess you wanted to merge this on **unique_id** property. So you can change your as

```
MERGE (c:Class {unique_id: class.unique_id})
```

Rest of the query looks ok.